# Hasclass usage in each()

Tags: jquery

Here is my script i want to add class if the div with class `.field-collection-container`, but i want to apply this to div which class don't include `.field-name-field-basic-info`, pls read the html,

```
$('.field-collection-container').each(function (index, obj) {
    if (($(this).hasClass('field-name-field-basic-info')) == false) {
        $(this).find('.field-items .content .field-item').each(function (index, obj) {
            //alert($(this).text());
            if ($(this).text() == '1') {
                $(this).addClass("tick1");
            } else {
                $(this).addClass("tick0");
            }
        });
    }
});
```

the html:

```
<div class="field-collection-container field-name-field-basic-info">not apply</div> 
<div class="field-collection-container">apply</div>
```

i use hasClass try to do this but not successful.

Comment: i liked Reigel's answer cuz he used the op's code.  too bad it's gone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code should work. However, instead of creating many unnecessary jQuery objects, you can use `not` method for excluding elements and `addClass` method for adding class names.

```
$('.field-collection-container')
     .not('.field-name-field-basic-info')
     .find('.field-item').addClass(function() {
           return $(this).text() === '1' ? 'tick1' : 'tick0';
     });
```